# What is the meaning of “well-a-well”?

Tags: meaning, american-english

I've had a question from an English language student who is reading *[The Adventures of Tom Sawyer](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/195120-hang-the-boy-can-t-i-never-learn-anything-ain-t-he)*.

He has a problem understanding what 'well-a-well' means in the following quote. I've searched and can't find anything online.

Has anyone come across this before?  Do we interpret is as just a colloquial form of 'well' as introducing a point. Is it used in contemporary US? (I'm British). I did say to the student that maybe it would be better to read a book from the 20th or 21st century but I would still like to go back to him with some information if possible.

> Every time I let him off, my conscience does hurt me so, and every time I hit him my old heart almost breaks. **Well-a-well**, man that is born of woman is of few days and full of trouble, as the Scripture says, and I reckon it's so.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not used in contemporary AmE.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! A good question. I would have interpreted it as "oh well", but I couldn't be sure.

Answer (score 4):

The OED attributes this now rare construct to Scottish and Irish English (northern) with the sense of 'expressing surprise, anticipation, resignation, or acquiescence'. It gives among several examples:

*The old woman tried to comfort her, beginning with her accustomed, ‘Well-a-well!’* (Elizabeth Gaskell, *Mary Barton*, 1848) and 
*Tam simply wad say, ‘Weel-a-weel, I'll jist by your counsel be guided.’* (David Willox, *Poems*, 1898).

Answer (score -1):

It can be reconstructed from the context as an exclamation (blend):
'Well, well (, well)!'

Here is an example from Cambridge Dictionary:

'He's decided to give up his job and move to Seattle with her." "Well, well - that's what love does for you."